# Connected to Wifi but not internet

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have S4 ,I have a full 5 bar signal on the WiFi but no internet

if I try to browse internet it says : the server at www.google.com can't be found,becasue the DNS look faild.
 I tried connecting / reconnecting, turning off the phone and restarting it but no Connection.
while the other devices such as I phone ,another Galaxy are OK

please advise what do to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static ip address and gateway address. It's also possible to edit the nameserver. You also need a route for the interface. You can use the route command to add a route. When you have a terminal emulation and root user you can type route -h to show a little help screen. To add a route try this: route add default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev xxx.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but how to route ? I don't know how to do it

Comment: Thank you , I forgot to metion that my problem is connecting to my Company Netwrok , IT says he can't connect directly to the server following your advise

Comment: Thank you , I forgot to metion that my problem is only happens when i am at the office,while at home it is OK . our corporate IT guy says he can't connect me directly to the server as per your advice becasue it is private phone .....another advise please